# How to check if software is or was installed

Tags: windows, registry

How can I check If a software is installed on windows??

Furthermore this program could have been deleted, then, How can I check If software was installed on windows in a determinate date??

Comment: You can do that if the program which got deleted want you to know. Generally, programs after uninstallation, removes their traces cuz they are no more needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about past dates but for present you can query the registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

(might also need to check HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall if you're on a 64-bit machine)

to find the program you want. Each one will have an DisplayName value which will tell you the program name.

follow the answers from this question - [Is there Uninstall a program batch for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995241/is-there-uninstall-a-program-batch-for-windows)

Comment: Thanks. It's ok for me for to know if a software is installed on windows, but I also need to know if software WAS installed in a determinate date.