# Repair programs in Windows programatically in C++ - maybe somehow by WinAPI?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry, windows-installer

I want to run from my C++ application the **repair** for other application - execute programatically what will happen when I manually select **repair** option for program in `Windows->Control Panel->Program`.

For **remove** option, I could just search registry for:

- `KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`
  on a 64-bit machine)

And than use the `UninstallString` to find which command I have to execute with `System()` function.

But how to run **repair** in the similar way? There is no such position in registry for programs like `RepairString`.

I want to find general method for all programs (of course I mean the programs that left information in registry).

**Additional question:** is it possible that applications listed by e.g `MsiEnumProductsEx` don't have their `UninstallString` registry entry?

p.s.
Info about registry entires for remove option I took from great Pat's post:

[Is there Uninstall a program batch for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995241/is-there-uninstall-a-program-batch-for-windows)

Comment: Note that not all programs have a repair option in Control Panel.

Comment: I know, but I want to run it for the programs that have it. In the most common way.

Comment: There is no "common" way. Different types of installers (MSI, InstallShield, InstallAware, etc) implement recovery in different ways (if at all), and Windows is unaware of those ways.

Comment: But programs like CCleaner etc. have the functionality to run that repair. I have found that there is something like 'ModifyPath' in registry - maybe it's a good way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually installation packages are created using MSI apis http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372860(v=vs.85).aspx

[WIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) is used to write MSI packages. Start with http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

If the program was installed with the Microsoft Installer, it is possible to call MSIEXEC with an appropriate set of switches. The switches are documented in the TechNet [Docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_Repair).

But even if you use this, the repair options differ extremely. And in a lot of cases you can't launch the repair if the original MSI files are no longer available (CD isn't inserted, or the downloaded file is already deleted).